# SQL pivot with variable lines

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

I have to get a variable amount of lines into columns.  I have something like:

```
EMP                 EMP_ID  DIV_ID  ALLOCATION
Smith, Tom          3605    11300   20.00
Smith, Tom          13605   11310   80.00
Benetar, Pat        7460    11012   25.00
Benetar, Pat        7460    11015   75.00
Walkin, Chris       13892   11012   90.00
Walkin, Chris       13892   11015   10.00
Kent, Clark         12262   10015   50.00
Kent, Clark         12262   11210   25.00
Kent, Clark         12262   11220   25.00
```

What I am looking for is something like:

```
EMP           EMP_ID        DIV_ID_01     DIV_01_ALOC    DIV_ID_02     DIV_02_ALOC    DIV_ID_03     DIV_03_ALOC
Smith, Tom    3605          11300         20.00          11310         80.00
Benetar, Pat  13605         11012         25.00          11015         75.00
Walkin, Chris 13892         11012         90.00          11015         10.00
Kent, Clark   12262         11015         50.00          11210         25.00          11220         25.00
```

I would like to avoid using a large amount of CASE statements.  I am trying now to work with pivots, but am having a tough time with headers.

Comment: For which RDBMS? and what did you try?

Comment: case statements perform better than pivots a lot of the time. you might want to consider using them.  You'd have to use 2 pivots to get this result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED:

After a couple of attempts, I came up with the solution below which utilizes two `PIVOT` functions and a `GROUP BY` in order to match your expected result.

Here is the code below. NOTE: This is meant for SQL Server 2005+

```
with testdata(Emp, EMP_ID, DIV_ID, ALLOCATION)
as
(
select 'Smith, Tom',3605, 11300,20.00
union all
select 'Smith, Tom',3605, 11310, 80.00
union all
select 'Benetar, Pat',7460, 11012,25.00
union all
select 'Benetar, Pat',7460, 11015,75.00
union all
select 'Walkin, Chris',13892, 11012, 90.00
union all
select 'Walkin, Chris', 13892, 11015, 10.00
union all
select 'Kent, Clark', 12262, 10015, 50.00
union all
select 'Kent, Clark', 12262, 11210, 25.00
union all
select 'Kent, Clark', 12262, 11220, 25.00
)       
SELECT Emp
,EMP_ID
,MAX([Div1]) AS DIV_ID_01
,MAX([Alloc1]) AS DIV_01_ALOC
,MAX([Div2]) AS DIV_ID_02
,MAX([Alloc2]) AS DIV_02_ALOC
,MAX([Div3]) AS DIV_ID_03
,MAX([Alloc3]) AS DIV_03_ALOC
FROM (
    SELECT *
    ,cast(dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id 
            ORDER BY div_id asc) AS nvarchar) AS [emp_rnk]
    ,'Alloc' + cast(dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id 
            ORDER BY div_id asc) AS nvarchar) AS [piv_Alloc_rnk] 
    ,'Div' + cast(dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id 
            ORDER BY div_id asc) AS nvarchar) AS [piv_Div_rnk]
FROM testdata td
) query

/* After both PIVOT functions are compplete, it still returns a single row for each EMP_ID. 
 So further aggregation is needed to 'flatten' the result. */

PIVOT (Max(Div_id) FOR [piv_Div_rnk] IN ([Div1],[Div2],[Div3])) AS pivot1
PIVOT (Max(Allocation) FOR [piv_Alloc_rnk] in([Alloc1],[Alloc2],[Alloc3])) AS pivot2

/* Since there is only one value in each of the columns created by the PIVOTS for each EMP_ID taking 
the MAX() value and grouping by EMP and EMP_ID flattens the result down to the desired output. */ 

GROUP BY emp, emp_id
ORDER BY DIV_ID_01 DESC
```

Comment: this is for a single column pivot.. not really helpful when you need two columns per row..

Comment: True. I noticed that after posting. I've updated my answer with a multi PIVOT solution that brings over both columns.

Comment: Awesome use of the multi PIVOT Chris!  This worked great.  As a matter of fact, I got all the solutions to work, this was just the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, if you try to use dynamic PIVOT here, you would end up needing a query that looks something like this.

```
SELECT  [EMP],
        [EMP_ID],
        MIN(DIV_ID_1) [DIV_ID_1],
        SUM(DIV_1_ALOC) [DIV_1_ALOC],
        MIN(DIV_ID_2) [DIV_ID_2],
        SUM(DIV_2_ALOC) [DIV_2_ALOC],
        MIN(DIV_ID_3) [DIV_ID_3],
        SUM(DIV_3_ALOC) [DIV_3_ALOC]
FROM    (SELECT [EMP],
                [EMP_ID],
                [DIV_ID],
                [ALLOCATION],
                CONCAT('DIV_ID_',DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [EMP] ORDER BY [DIV_ID])) ID_RN,
                CONCAT('DIV_',DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [EMP] ORDER BY [DIV_ID]),'_ALOC') ALLOC_RN
         FROM   EmpTable
        ) t 
PIVOT   ( 
        MIN([DIV_ID]) 
        FOR ID_RN IN ([DIV_ID_1],[DIV_ID_2],[DIV_ID_3]) ) p1 
PIVOT   ( 
        SUM([ALLOCATION]) 
        FOR ALLOC_RN IN ([DIV_1_ALOC],[DIV_2_ALOC],[DIV_3_ALOC]) ) p2
GROUP BY [EMP],
        [EMP_ID]
```

You would need to dynamically create the SELECT and also the PIVOT columns because of the double pivot.

On the other hand, if you use CASE statements, you'll only need to dynamically create the SELECT, since that query would look like

```
SELECT  [EMP],
        [EMP_ID],
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN [DIV_ID] END) [DIV_ID_1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN [ALLOCATION] END) [DIV_1_ALOC],
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN [DIV_ID] END) [DIV_ID_2],
        SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN [ALLOCATION] END) [DIV_2_ALOC],
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN [DIV_ID] END) [DIV_ID_3],
        SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN [ALLOCATION] END) [DIV_3_ALOC]
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [EMP] ORDER BY [DIV_ID]) RN 
            FROM    EmpTable
        ) t
GROUP BY [EMP],
        [EMP_ID]
```

Your dynamic statment would look something like

```
DECLARE @CaseSelect VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @CaseSelect = COALESCE(@CaseSelect + ',','') 
                + 'MIN(CASE WHEN RN = ' + RN + ' THEN [DIV_ID] END) [DIV_ID_' + RN + '],'
                + 'SUM(CASE WHEN RN = ' + RN + ' THEN [ALLOCATION] END) [DIV_' + RN + '_ALOC]'
FROM    (
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [EMP] ORDER BY [DIV_ID])) RN 
    FROM EmpTable 
) t 
ORDER BY RN

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET     @SQL = '
    SELECT  [EMP],
            [EMP_ID], '
            + @CaseSelect + '
    FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [EMP] ORDER BY [DIV_ID]) RN 
        FROM    EmpTable
    ) t
    GROUP BY [EMP], [EMP_ID]
'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Replacing `EmpTable` with your actual table name ofcourse.